# Enumerating feasible solutions to the subset sum problem using Gibbs sampling

Tags: python, markov-chain-montecarlo, combinatorics, gibbs

Given a set of $m$ strictly positive real numbers $W = \{ w_{1}, \dots, w_{m} \}$, I want to find subsets of $W$ whose sum is less than or equal to a maximum value $N$ using Gibbs sampling. To do this, we define a binary random variable $X_{i}$ for each $w_{i} \in W$, where $X_{i} = 1$ implies $w_{i}$ is included in a given subset, and $X_{i} = 0$ implies it is not included. We can then define a joint distribution on $X_{1}, \dots, X_{m}$ as \begin{align} 
P(X_{1}, \dots, X_{m}) \triangleq 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{Z} \, \epsilon, \, & \text{if } \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_{i} w_{i} = 0 \\
\frac{1}{Z} \, \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} X_{i} w_{i}, & \text{if } 0 < \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_{i} w_{i} \leq N \\
0, & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\epsilon > 0$ and $Z$ is some normalising constant. If $\phi(X_{1}, \dots X_{m}) \triangleq Z \times P(X_{1}, \dots, X_{m})$, then we can enumerate the desired subsets using a Gibbs sampler that samples from the conditional distribution:
\begin{align}
P(X_{i} \, | \, X_{\setminus i}) = \dfrac{ \phi(X_{1}, \dots, X_{m}) }{ \phi(X_{i} = 0, X_{\setminus i}) + \phi(X_{i} = 1, X_{\setminus i})},
\end{align}
where $X_{\setminus i}$ denotes all the RVs excluding $X_{i}$. The python code for this Gibbs sampler is included below:

```
import numpy as np


def gibbs_sampler(W, N, number_of_samples=int(1e4), epsilon=0.01):
    # Initialize variables
    samples = []
    m = len(W)
    W_total = 0
    x = np.zeros(m, dtype=int)

    # Gibbs sampling
    for _ in range(number_of_samples):
        for i in range(m):
            # Remove current x[i]
            W_total -= W[i] * x[i]
            x[i] = 0

            # Sample a new value for x[i]
            if W_total + W[i] <= N:
                P = (
                    (W_total + W[i]) / (2 * W_total + W[i])
                    if W_total > 0
                    else W[i] / (W[i] + epsilon)
                )
                if np.random.rand() < P:
                    x[i] = 1
                    W_total += W[i]

        # Add the sample to the list
        samples.append(1.0 * x)

    return samples


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setup
    W = np.array([6, 7, 8, 5, 9])
    N = 15

    # Generate samples
    samples = gibbs_sampler(W, N)
    for i, sample in enumerate(np.unique(samples, axis=0)):
        print(f"Sample {i}: {sample}, sum: {np.dot(sample, W)}.")
```

My questions are:

- Is this formulation correct, or even reasonable? How do I improve it? I want to "favour" subsets with larger sums, so I decided their likelihood should be proportional to their sum. However, this requires the introduction of the $\epsilon$ parameter to ensure the empty set has a non-zero probability of occuring.
- Is it possible to reformulate this problem and create a Gibbs sampler than enumerates subsets with a sum between a non-zero lower bound and an upperbound? This is the real problem I'd like to solve.

Comment: Yes, this sounds correct in terms of Gibbs sampling. The distribution is your choice and another would see different Gibbs behaviour. One could pick the index $i$ at each Gibbs step proportionally to the weight $\omega_i$ and also move several $X_j$'s at once. And setting a lower bound on the sum is equally manageable.

Comment: Regarding my second question: Let's say I have the weights $W = \{ 6, 7, 8 \}$, a lower bound sum of 10, and an upper bound sum of 15. If my initial sample is $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and I sample the binary variables in order, then I can't ever add or remove any elements from the current subset, because I'll violate the bounds. How do I get around this? I'm really hoping I'm missing something very obvious here.

Comment: If you move two ot them at once, it would work.

Comment: This is blocked Gibbs sampling then? For a general $m$ weights, with an upper and lower bound sum, we would have to somehow determine which subset of variables we can jointly sample from without violating the bounds. Isn't this a difficult problem in and of itself? If it is solvable, wouldn't we still run the risk of sampling from the full joint distribution, which is prohibitively expensive? I was hoping sampling could be kept to sampling from conditional distributions on a single binary RV, but it doesn't seem doable.

Comment: Using Metropolis-Hastings (MH), one does not have to find or optimise which block size is needed for moving more freely between the bounds, instead select a block size at random at each iteration, then the block indices at random, with potentially different weights, and move by a MH step if the proposed move is (a) between the bounds and (b) accepted by the MH accept/reject step. Otherwise duplicate the current value.